# How to build tensorflow lite with C API support?

Tags: bazel, tensorflow-lite

In the official github repo and documentation it appears that there is no predefined bazel target for tensorflow lite with C API support.

I'm not very familiar with bazel, but it seems like there is a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can find an experimental C library for TensorFlow Lite in [lite/experimental/c/BUILD](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/experimental/c/BUILD#L56). There's also a [shared library target](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/experimental/c/BUILD#L19) that you can build with `bazel`, e.g.,

```
bazel build -c opt --cxxopt=--std=c++11 \
  //tensorflow/lite/experimental/c:libtensorflowlite_c.so
```

If you wish to build for Android, you'll use something like:

```
bazel build -c opt --cxxopt=--std=c++11 --config=android_arm64 \
  //tensorflow/lite/experimental/c:libtensorflowlite_c.so
```

Comment: This is no more experimental, It is now building with `bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/lite/c:tensorflowlite_c`

Comment: It needs to change building command as follows for TensorFlow 2.7.0.bazel   build -c opt --cxxopt=--std=c++14 //tensorflow/lite/c:libtensorflowlite_c.so

Comment: For building TensorFlow Lite 2.7.0 with selecting TensorFlow operators: bazel build --jobs 4 --verbose_failures -c opt --config=monolithic --define=tflite_convert_with_select_tf_ops=true --define=with_select_tf_ops=true --cxxopt=--std=c++14 //tensorflow/lite/c:libtensorflowlite_c.so